# Being employed in two EU countries simultaneously

Tags: tax-law, germany, immigration, netherlands

Is it possible (legal) to be employed in two jobs (full time) in two different European countries at the same time?

Secondly, is it possible to have work permits of two countries simultaneously being a non-EU citizen? For e.g. now when I have started working in Netherlands and applied for a residence permit here will they inform the German officials about my **auftehlatserlaubnis** in Germany (which is still valid)?... As is in this case my primary address will not be in Germany, is it possible that my German permit gets void/cancelled?

Comment: Are you really talking about two **full-time** jobs? In Germany, the contracts for a full-time job usually preclude another full-time job, and they generally specify the place of work. That matters e.g. when one lives in one state and works in another, and the public holidays differ.

Comment: I believe a lot depends on the specifics of your residence permit but I'm pretty sure you have to inform the German officials. I would also be very surprised if the officials in the Netherlands had not inquired regarding existing residence permits for other EU countries. I would be astonished if you could have work permits for two EU countries (without being a EU citizen). Not informing officials or lying on applications could void your permits.

Comment: No, it's not, and we answered your question [a month ago](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189108/multiple-jobs-in-eu/189110). It does not get more legal, the more you ask. Laws don't change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think German law would allow you to work two full-time jobs, because it would be too many working hours and bad for your health and they don't like that. Whether it is allowed to be *employed* twice (if you manage to be employed for 40 hours a week while working only twenty), I don't know. Your two employers wouldn't be happy if they find out, obviously.

If the second employment is another country, that doesn't matter. What matters is how many hours you work. Two jobs in Germany, or one in Germany and one elsewhere, is exactly the same as far as working hours are concerned.

And having two work permits is fine. You can use them to work 20 hours in each country. If you have a 40 hour job in Germany and sign a contract in another country for another 40 hour job, they'd expect you to quit one job. You'd have the right to work in A, and the right to work in B, but because of labour laws you don't have the right to work two full time jobs. Just like a dual citizen.

Comment: Specifically in a German context, employers have a duty to deduct correct taxes and to ensure that working time limits (per day, per week, rest time between shifts) are met. For this, a German employer will need to know how much an employee works and earns elsewhere.

Comment: For more details on this, we extensively answered that question by the OP a month ago on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189108/multiple-jobs-in-eu/189110). I guess they are still looking to do it, despite being told it's not going to work.